# How do i fix this error? TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str: discord.py

Tags: python, typeerror, discord.py

Hey there i am coding a discord bot and i decided to add a leveling system to it. For if a member of the server is active enough and types in chat enough they can level up. This is what i have atm ("For the leveling system")

```
    import discord
    from discord.ext.commands import Bot
    from discord.ext import commands
    from random import randint
    import random
    import asyncio
    import pickle
    import os
    import json
    from itertools import cycle
    import time
    os.chdir('C:\Users\Desktop\MyBot')



@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
        users = json.load(f)

    await update_data(users, member)


    with open('users.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(users, f)

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
        users = json.load(f)

    await update_data(users, message.author)
    await add_experience(users, message.authors, 5)
    await level_up(users, message.author, message.channel)


    with open('users.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(users, f)
async def update_data(users, user):
    if not user.id in users:
        users[user.id] = []
        users[user.id]['experience'] = 1
        users[user.id]['level'] = 1

async def add_experience(users, user, exp):
    users[user.id]['experience'] += exp

async def level_up(users, user, channel):
    experience = users[user.id]['experience']
    lvl_start = users[user.id]['level']
    lvl_end = int(experience ** (1/4))

    if lvl_start < lvl_end:
        await bot.send_messgae(channel, '{} have leveled up to level {}'.format(user.mention, lvl_end))
        user[user.id]['level'] = lvl_end
```

This is the exact error i am getting.

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MYNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 307, in _run_event
    yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\MYNAME\Desktop\MyBot\CrestBot.py", line 36, in on_message
    await update_data(users, message.author)
  File "C:\Users\MYNAME\Desktop\MyBot\CrestBot.py", line 46, in update_data
    users[user.id]['experience'] = 0
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: on which line do you get the error?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/kj6new Nazar Khan, This is where it says i am getting my errors.

Comment: @Zemo  - please [edit] the question to indicate the line where you get the error.  A link to an external site is not good enough.  Particularly a link to a screen shot rather than text.

Comment: That is not really how slicing works in a list

Comment: I updated the post. hopefully thats better

Answer (score 0):

Basically it seems like `users[user.id]` is a list and you are trying to index it like a dictionary (for example `users[user.id]['experience']`).  Without more information on the user model and what `users` is it's hard to suggest an exact fix.

Comment: What do you think i should fix it to?

Comment: It's the code `users[user.id] = [];users[user.id]['experience'] = 1;users[user.id]['level'] = 1`.  The first line needs to be        `users[user.id] = {}`

Comment: Thanks Martin Bonner. The problem is fixed!

Answer (score 0):

Then answer to this was

```
    the code users[user.id] = [] #This line needs to be changed to this users[user.id] = {}
    users[user.id]['experience'] = 1;users
    [user.id]['level'] = 1.
```